# How to change cell shape during calculations in LAMMPS?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, lammps

I was doing some calculations using LAMMPS and wondered if there was a way to change the cell shape during npt or nvt calculations (in the latter, changing the cell shape while keeping the volume fixed).

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if there's any update you can give us after all these months? Also, are you still actively in need of an answer to this question?